# Power Query on SQL database returns "Could not find stored procedure ..."

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

This is a spreadsheet with a number of queries against a SQL database in Power Query. It runs fine on other users' computers but not this one. He is a new employee in this area so it has never been tried on his computer before.

The query returns the following error:

> DataSource.Error Microsoft SQL: could not find stored procedure 'usp_vd_rollup_query'.
>
> Details:
> DataSourceKind=SQL
> DataSourcePath=sage2018.local;live
> Message:=Could not find stored procedure 'usp_vd_rollup_query'.
> ErrorCode=-2146232060
> Number=2812
> Class=16

The error code apparently means that the database was not found or is not accessible. However, the query does run on other computers. The query uses shared database credentials which are stored in the connection record.

In the past I have had issues with other uses surrounding privacy and security. I have compared all the security and privacy settings to another computer where the Power Query runs successfully without success.

Comment: What credentials does the user have for the database connection? ie are they setup on the database as a distinct user, or do they use a common account? It may be that the database user id needs to be permissioned for that stored procedure?

Comment: The connection was set up to use common credentials, but I'm positive the answer lay in this kind of area.  Anyway,  I decided to replace his tired old  computer altogether. He getting a brand new one tomorrow and I'm confident it'll be fine.